# How can I achieve $(document).ready type behavior for AJAX content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`$(document).ready(handler)` executes once the DOM is fully loaded.  If content is later added to the page using AJAX, which contains a `$(document).ready(handler)` function, this function is executed immediately, per the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Additionally, `.ready` can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document.

This is not what I want, however :)

How can I achieve this `.ready` type of functionality for data loaded via AJAX after `.ready` has already fired, in a cross-browser compliant manner?

**EDIT:**
Here's a very simplified example.  I do have a problem I'm trying to solve, but I'm more interested in understanding the way to do this properly.

Basically, the .ready function in ajaxPage.html is firing before importantDependency.js is completely loaded, so the first load of ajaxPage, importantDependency is missing, but subsequent loads see it.

index.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("The document is ready");

    $('#myButton').click(function() {
      $('<div></div>').dialog({
        open: function () {
          $(this).load('ajaxPage.html');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
...
```

ajaxPage.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="importantDependency.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready() {
    $('#thing').leverageImportantDependency();
  });
</script>
...
```

**EDIT 2:**
I want to do this *FROM* the loaded content, not from the page calling the content.  Modifying the calling page means duplicating code in every instance where this is called.  I'd like the behavior to be attached to the content, not the page calling it.

Comment: you mean you want to fire once ajax completes//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you will want to do something like this:

```
$("#container").load(function(html) {
    // container has been filled up, and is 
    // ready for JS processing
    doSomethingWithNewContent();
});
```

That is to say, fire off something *once* the content has been replaced, by utilizing the appropriate ajax callback. Other examples include:

```
$.get("foo.html", function(html) {
    $("#container").html(html);
    $("#container").find(".foo").fancyThing();
});

$.ajax({ 
      url: 'foo.html',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(html) {
                   $("#container").html(html).find(".foo").hide();
               }
     });
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.load/

EDIT: From what I understand from your edit, you want attach something, such as a an event handler or a plugin to some elements that keep getting replaced. There are a few ways to do this:

1. In the success callbacks, as
   demonstrated above.
2. Using [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or
   [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
3. Using [`.liveQuery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I'm not doing it this way because this component is loaded in a lot of pages.  So if I were to add the logic to the ajax success callback, I'd have to duplicate the code.  I'd prefer to keep it in the loaded content.  Any ideas in that direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get your question, but when you have retrieved the data, you simply do whatever you want with it in the success handler of the ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: pageUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            $(".someContainer").html(data);
            // TODO: This is your ready handler for the new content

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified in my question.  I'm trying not to use the callback of the ajax function because it will mean a lot of duplication.  I'm looking to keep my functionality in the loaded content.

Comment: How about having one function that handles it? So inside success you simply do:

success: successFunction

where successFunction has 1 parameter which is data and you can do all your logic within it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the complete property of an JQuery Ajax call. The complete function is called after success or error.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "foo",
  complete: function({
    // I'm done
  }
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I really need to create this behavior from the other side of things, in the content that I'm loading and not where it's called.  I can not break the javascript out of ajaxPage.html, and I'd like to keep importantDependency.js in ajaxPage.html, since that is the only page that uses it.